# Exclude all files under all nested directories from a git diff, using .git/info/attributes

Tags: git

I need to permanently exclude all files under one directory and all its subdirectories from git diff, using .git/info/attributes

adding "-diff" lines in attributes works greatly for one level, but I couldn't find a way to do that recursively

so for dir/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/.. and files under all of them, `dir/* -diff` works for one level, `dir/**/* -diff` works for the second level, and so on.

Can this be done with one line?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the * and just use `dir/ -diff`.

Or better yet, use `* -diff` and put the .gitattributes file in the dir directory.

Comment: "dir/ -diff" didn't work, I am using git version 1.7.3.5, and I actually need to do this from .git/info/attributes and not individual .gitattributes (question updated)